# getting error through sed command in unix

Tags: unix, sed

I have to replace the following value in all the xml files so the value is

```
tcp://pondevpms1.fm.rbsgrp.net:6033,pondevpms2.fm.rbsgrp.net:6033
```

and the value with it need to be replaces is shown below

```
tcp://pondevpms1:3063
```

so i have fired the below command inside the directory that contain all the xml's

```
sed -i 's/tcp://pondevpms1.fm.rbsgrp.net:6033,pondevpms2.fm.rbsgrp.net:6033/tcp://pondevpms1:6063 /g' *.xml
```

but i am getting this below error please advise what is missing ..?

below the error that i am getting rite now

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your delimiter from / to something else like #
So your command would look like this

```
sed -i 's#tcp://pondevpms1.fm.rbsgrp.net:6033,pondevpms2.fm.rbsgrp.net:6033#tcp://pondevpms1:6063#g' *.xml
```

Alternatively, you could escape all your slashes, but that wouldn't look very nice

Comment: the error is  sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'

Comment: okay, then this should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the error, but I would bet that the slashes in your text are causing you trouble. Since you are using `/` as the sed operator you need to escape it in your text : `\/` for every `/`.

However, since your text has alot of slashes and sed can use other characters as the operator, I would just use a pipe as the sed operator;

```
sed -i 's|tcp://pondevpms1.fm.rbsgrp.net:6033,pondevpms2.fm.rbsgrp.net:6033|tcp://pondevpms1:6063 |g' *.xml
```

Comment: The error that i am getting is  sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is incorrect. You can use any separator, so avoid '/' as it conflicts with the contents, I personally use # because it is seldom used except in comments.

```
sed -i 's#tcp://pondevpms1.fm.rbsgrp.net:6033,pondevpms2.fm.rbsgrp.net:6033#tcp://pondevpms1:6063#g' *.xml
```

Comment: "sed does not work 'in-place'" ??. What do you mean? That's what the `-i` flag does.

Comment: I said I was rusty. Now that's really confirmed :) Editing my answer!